# Trace and determinants in QFT's

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, integration, trace, functional-determinants

I'm trying to understand this paper: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.46.6490. It's about path integration with defects (theories on submanifolds). Let me here try to explain what in particular I'm having troubles understanding (without going into further details about this paper since it is quite technical).

In particular, in its Sec. IV:A they consider a line and a surface defect (of dim. p = 1 and q = 2 dimension respectively). I understand the steps until they wish to calculate:
\begin{equation}
\log\det\left( 1 - D \right) \ , \quad D \equiv (D^{11}_{b.c})^{-1} D^{12}_{b.c} (D^{22}_{b.c})^{-1} D^{21}_{b.c}
\end{equation}
where $D^{ij}_{b.c}$ is the spacetime propagator in between defect $i$ and $j$, where $i = 1$ is the line defect and $i = 2$ is the surface defect. When $j = i$, $D^{ii}_{b.c}$ is the propagator localized on its respective defect. We also have that $D^{21}_{b.c} = (D^{12}_{b.c})^\dagger$. The inverse, $(D^{ij}_{b.c})^{-1}$, is the differential operator found from the e.o.m. (subject to the b.c.'s on the defects), which generates the Dyson-Schwinger eq.

Whenever I encounter logarithms of determinants in QFT's I'm used to write it as a trace:
\begin{equation}
\log\det\left( 1 - D \right) = \text{tr}\log(1 - D) \ .
\end{equation}
According to the paper, this should equal:
\begin{equation}
\text{tr}\log(1 - D) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}dx \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dk_x}{2\,\pi} \log\!\left( 1 - \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dk_y}{2\,\pi} \frac{|G_{b.c.}^{12}(k_x, k_y)|^2)}{G_{b.c.}^{11}(k_x)  G_{b.c.}^{22}(k_x, k_y)} \right) \ .
\end{equation}
Here $G_{b.c.}^{ij}(k_x, k_y)$ is the corresponding momentum propagator given in terms of momentum flowing along the defects.

Now how do I prove above formula? I have several questions regarding this: why do I integrate over $x\in\mathbb{R}$ (and not $(x, y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$), and why is the integration over $k_y$ inside the logarithm?

I appreciate any help!